# Seeedstudio NFC Shield v2.0 I2C

Tags: arduino, nfc, i2c, spi, hce

I am using NFC shield v2.0 and it seems Sel0 and Sel1 pins are set for SPI mode and we cant change it (saw in schematic files). So is there any way to change the values on this pins via software(program) to make it to work for I2C mode?

and inDataExchange function is not a member of SPI.cpp library while it is in I2C.cpp library?
is there any way to make HCE work with SPI mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported modes of the PN532 chip on the NFC Shield do not depend on the interface used for communication (at least when it comes to NFC operating modes). So you should be able to send whatever commands you want over the SPI interface just as you would with the I2C interface.

With regard to the `inDataExchange` command, this command seems to be implemented in the current version of the library (see the [github repo](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/PN532/)).

And no, besides wiring the interface selection pins to a different value, there is no other way to change the interface mode at runtime.

Comment: So I can send apdu(aid commands) with SPI modes? can you elaborate on how to do it.. & thanks for your reply

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. The seeedstudio library has the same methods (writeCommand/readResponse) for SPI and I2C, so whatever PN532 commands you send would work with both, the I2C and the SPI low-level (HAL) drivers.

Comment: seeedstudio library is not having inDataExchange method for SPI and i want to transfer a string from phone using HCE. I'll try to use the library posted by you!

Comment: I am getting data in Hex on arduino serial monitor,now I want to convert it back to String(how to do this?) and I wrote a a code for Serial Client in C# where I am receiving the data sent on COM Port & i just want the string from the data I am sending from phone but unable to Separate from that Firmware Version, Found Something! Texts (because they are also coming on COM Port), I want to display Everything in RichTextBox(that is working) but how to just the string we got for other purpose?

Comment: @CoRRoDED34 You might want to ask a new question instead of posting your question as a comment to an existing answer.

Comment: Okay Sir! I Posted a new Question.